# Performance issues. modesetting vs xf86-video-intel

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel

There was a question about which there is no information on the Internet.  I really tried to search, and after 3 days I did not find anything.  No one knows why GNOME in a X.org session runs slower on a modesetting driver than on xf86-video-intel?  For example, interface freezes, fewer frames per second.

I studied some information on the methods of accelerating 2D and 3D graphics.  [SNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNA_(computer_graphics)), [UXA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UMA_Acceleration_Architecture), and [Glamor](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Glamor/).  As I understand it, SNA is a replacement for the old UXA, which uses 2D graphics acceleration through the graphics card in a native way.  But Glamor already uses [2D acceleration through OpenGL](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:The_Linux_Graphics_Stack_and_glamor.svg).  But isn't this essentially a slower way to implement graphics acceleration?

I also compared the FPS in the Minecraft game, there, using the modesetting driver (Glamor, DRI 3 options), the FPS is less by a couple of frames, and there are also small freezes.  What can be done to fix this?  Should I upgrade to a newer modesetting driver if it actually works slower?  Well and the most important thing.  Why is a driver that has not been updated since 2014 running faster than the one that is active? Thanks.

(I am currently on Intel core i5-8250U / Intel UHD Graphics 620)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is a driver that has not been updated since 2014 running faster
>   than the one that is active?

Probably system engineers that do deep debugging and comparison of the code could come up with an answer here. This is open source software. Different teams are working on different approaches. Apparently, the kernel developers did not yet get the modeset intel drivers, at least in some aspects, to the level of the older xorg drivers. Unless you can help as a developer yourself, your only option will be to wait.

The nomodeset kernel drivers get better with each kernel update. When I first installed Ubuntu 19.10, it defaulted to the modeset drivers. However, I had to move to the xorg drivers because I had intermittent graphical glitches (colored stripes, sometimes even the entire screen) with the kernel driver. Now, a few kernel versions further, I am again on the nomodeset driver and the issues are gone (except for an extremely small glitch when changing volume or brightness on full screen youtube video). But then, I am not a gamer or a user of other apps with very high graphics requirements, so I would not notice any possible fault in high-level graphics performance.